# ENS signature from header don't match with generated one

Tags: event-notification-service, verification

I've started messing up with the ENS, I set up everything and started receiving notifications. Now I'm writing logic for the notification signature verification and I can't get the signature to match with the hashed notification payload. I tried many variations, wrote the code in PHP and Java and I just can't get values to match. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong? Thanks

Php code

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input'); // notification payload
        $callbackSignatureKey = 'SIGNATURE_KEY_OBTAINED_ON_CALLBACK_CREATION';//callback signature key
        $key = base64_decode($signatureKey);//decoded key
        $signatureKey = $headers->get('X-Sfmc-Ens-Signature');//X-Sfmc-Ens-Signature from headers
        $generatedKey = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data , $key, true)); //does not match $signatureKey
```

Java Code (from the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ens-notification-signing.html)

```
Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode("Callback verification key"), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        String data = "notification payload";
        String actual = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
System.out.println(actual);
```

I get the same results from PHP and Java and the result is not matching the key provided in headers

Comment: Running in to the same issue. Did you ever resolve?

Comment: @Birdman in my case the issue was the callback signature key. It comes base64 encoded (even though there is no info about that in the docs) so I had to decode it before using it.